# Should we convert the tag [scrpage2] into an alias for a new tag [scrlayer-crpage]?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Over the years until now only 43 questions are tagged with [scrpage2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrpage2). Now, with recently published version 3.12 of KOMA-Script a successor package `scrlayer-scrpage` came out, that is now recommended in favour of `scrpage2`. Two cites from English KOMA-Script doc `scrguien` (*start of chapter 6, the basic description of `scrlayer-scrpage`*):

> …  the additional package `scrlayer-scrpage` provides a user interface, which is largely compatible with `scrpage2` and based on `scrlayer`. Thus, if you are already familiar with `scrpage2` and refrain from using dirty tricks, like calling internal commands of `scrpage2` directly, it should be easy for you to use `scrlayer-scrpage` as a drop-in replacement.

> … if you are using a KOMA-Script class, the usage of package `scrlayer-scrpage` is recommended. Of course you can use `scrlayer-scrpage` with other classes, namely the LATEX standard classes, too.

Therefore my question(s): Should we

- create a new tag [scrlayer-scrpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrlayer-scrpage) and convert the existing tag [scrpage2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrpage2) to an alias?
- create a new tag [scrlayer-scrpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrlayer-scrpage), but do not convert the existing tag [scrpage2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrpage2)?
- do nothing in the moment?

Regarding the last item: When would be a better/the right moment?

Comment: Having 43 tagged by one of them and 0 tagged by the other one, I would wait for a while and see what happens. No need to be pre-cautious too much about tagging in this case, it doesn't seem to have so much traffic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in a comment: Having 43 tagged by one of them and 0 tagged by the other one, I would wait for a while and see what happens. No need to be pre-cautious too much about tagging in this case, it doesn't seem to have so much traffic.

If there arose some confusion about those two tags, we can review the solution and then it can get easily sorted out, since the number of changes would be in units, not hundreds ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should create a new tag `scrlayer`. Although `scrlayer` will replace `scrpage2`, `scrlayer` has a complete difference syntax and mechanism so that you can't compare the two packages. The package `scrpage2` will be declared as obsolete however it will be part of the KOMA-bundle to be backward compatible.

For me the packages `scrlayer` and `scrpage2` are needing a separate tag.

Comment: that's especially true since `scrlayer` can be used for much more than to just create pagestyles. (cf. `scrlayer-notecolumn` for example)

Comment: Note, that `scrlayer`, `scrlayer-scrpage` and (in reaction to cgnieder’s comment) `scrlayer-notecolumn` are _different_ packages. The two latter are just based on the first one. Nethertheless we could do it in this way, when we would add [tag:header-footer] for `scrlayer-scrpage` and [tag:marginpar] or a yet to be created [tag:margin-notes] for `scrlayer-notecolumn`.